# Java spark groupByKey with key1 and do aggregateByKey with key2 on groupedRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to do one simple java spark application which does the following

Input Data csv format : key1,key2,data1,data2

Basically what I am trying to do here is,

First I am mapping each line by key1 and then doing a groupByKey operation on that rdd.

```java
JavaRDD<String> viewRdd = sc.textFile("testfile.csv", 1);
JavaPairRDD<String, String> customerIdToRecordRDD = viewRdd
    .mapToPair(w -> new Tuple2<String, String>(w.split(",")[0], w));
JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<String>> groupedByKey1RDD = customerIdToRecordRDD.groupByKey();
System.out.println(customerIdToRecordGropedRDD.count());
```

Now my problem is, I need to do an aggregateByKey with key2 on each group from groupedByKey1RDD. Is there any way to convert Iterable into an RDD ?? or am I missing something here. I am new to this, any help will be

**Example input and expected output :**

> id_1,time0,10,10
>
> id_2,time1,0,10
>
> id_1,time1,11,10
>
> id_1,time0,1,10
>
> id_2,time1,10,10

Output is grouped by 1st column and then aggregated by 2nd column (aggregate logic is to simply add column3 and column4):

```
id_1 : time0 : { sum1 : 11, sum2 : 20} ,
       time1 : { sum1 : 11, sum2 : 10}

id_2 : time1 : { sum1 : 10, sum2 : 20}
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample of csv data and expected output?

Comment: @abaghel Added sample input and output

Comment: What is the spark version you are using? And do you want to use RDD, because this can be easily solved and will be more manageable using Dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution using Spark 2.0 and Dataframe. Please let me know if you still want to use RDD.

```
public class SparkGroupBySample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //SparkSession
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("SparkGroupBySample")
            .master("local")
            .getOrCreate();     
    //Schema
    StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] { 
            new StructField("key1", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("key2", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("data1", DataTypes.IntegerType, true, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("data2", DataTypes.IntegerType, true, Metadata.empty())});
    //Read csv
    Dataset<Row> dataSet = spark.read().format("csv").schema(schema).option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",").load("c:\\temp\\sample.csv");
    dataSet.show();     
    //groupBy and aggregate
    Dataset<Row> dataSet1 = dataSet.groupBy("key1","key2").sum("data1","data2").toDF("key1","key2","sum1","sum2");
    dataSet1.show();
    //stop
    spark.stop();
   }
}
```

Here is the output.

```
+----+-----+----+----+
|key1| key2|sum1|sum2|
+----+-----+----+----+
|id_1|time1|  11|  10|
|id_2|time1|  10|  20|
|id_1|time0|  11|  20|
+----+-----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thank you very much @abaghel for this. I have not used Dataframes before so have very little knowledge on it. I am trying to do more complicated user defined aggregate methods instead of just sum which I belive we can use with dataframes also. But if possible, I would like to know how we can acheive the same with RDDs. And I am using spark 2.0

Comment: With Spark 2.0 you should be using Dataframes. Yes you can do different type of aggregation by passing inbuilt function to agg method or you can call user defined function.Please check "org.apache.spark.sql.functions". Example  -   dataSet.groupBy("c1").agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list("c2"));

Comment: I was trying to aggregate and create a new pojo with some additional derived values. Is that possible using dataframes? Thanks!

Comment: Basically what I am looking for an output similar to this { map of key1 : { map of key2 : [ list of aggregated pojos ]} } .

Comment: If you have your Dataframe from input data you can call map or flatmap functions to create desired output. You can even run SQL queries by creating temp table on your input data. Please check http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html for more details.